# No interviewed man/men wanted to

Tags: grammatical-number

> - No interviewed man wanted to put the system in his trouser pocket, as opposed to two of four females.
>
> or
>
> - No interviewed men wanted to put the system in their trouser pockets, as opposed to two of four females.

In this sentence, should it be `man`or `men`? I would say `man` but Word Grammar Check is happy with both. Would this make a difference in the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Seems it's hard for one man to put a 'system' into multiple trouser pockets at the same time. Also, if it's man, then the use of gender-free singular they might be in question.

Comment: @Let's It is definitely physically possible to put this system in multiple trouser pockets at once (think smart-phone + connected on-ear headphones). Additionally, would a singular use of trouser pocket not mean they have only one? I also don't quite understand which part you mean by "gender-free singular", would you care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language* deals with this issue in its section 'The negative determinatives *no* and *none*' (p388).

The CGEL compares the statements:

- No juvenile was admitted.
- No juveniles were admitted.

It says that these '*are semantically equivalent: the distinction between singular and plural is here neutralised*'.

The CGEL goes on to list cases where the singular or the plural is 'required' or 'more natural'. So, the singular is required in *'He has no father*', since you can only have one (biological) father. The singular is more natural in *'He has no job'*, since you usually have only one job. Conversely, the plural is more natural in *She has no children*, since according to the CGEL *'it is more usual to have two or more children than just one'*.

In the present case there is no semantic difference and no 'requirement' for either the singular or the plural. For me the plural, *No interviewed men wanted...* sounds a little more natural since it is followed by the plural *in their trouser pockets*.

Comment: Sorry, Shoe, I felt the Qn needed making more felicitous; your (CGEL's) examples are far better.. You might like to adjust your answer. Sorry about the extra work. But have a +1.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth— Sorry if this sounds like nitpicking, but shouldn't there be a resumptive pronoun "it" in your comment above _... I felt the Qn needed making it_ more felicitous? :)

Comment: @405662 No. I saw the dog needed it feeding? I saw the woman needed it/her helping? I was told the fence needed it repairing? All incorrect.

Comment: You might also like to include the fourth alternative, _We have no peas_, where the plural form (indeterminate, I'd say: probably non-count, but a whimsical 'We have three peas' _is_ possible) is, I'd say, mandatory.

Comment: I saw the woman wanted her husband wore the official attire...  -  This is evolving English style.  It, once in the past, had been "I saw (that) the woman wanted (that) her husband wore the official....